# Error occurred decoding the EPSG code EPSG%3A3857 in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, javascript, wms, wcs

My application is throwing the `NoSuchAuthorityCodeException` error although the layer preview in geoserver is working perfectly, they are not visualizing in the app. I have just checked the logs and found this error

```
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Error occurred decoding the espg code EPSG%3A3857
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.read(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:266)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.read(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:90)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.parseRequestKVP(Dispatcher.java:1545)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:692)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:255)
```

Caused by

```
Caused by: org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchAuthorityCodeException: No authority was defined for code "EPSG%3A3857". Did you forget "AUTHORITY:NUMBER"?
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.ManyAuthoritiesFactory.noSuchAuthority(ManyAuthoritiesFactory.java:478)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.ManyAuthoritiesFactory.getAuthorityFactory(ManyAuthoritiesFactory.java:457)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.ManyAuthoritiesFactory.getCRSAuthorityFactory(ManyAuthoritiesFactory.java:532)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.AuthorityFactoryAdapter.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(AuthorityFactoryAdapter.java:778)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.ThreadedAuthorityFactory.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(ThreadedAuthorityFactory.java:635)
    at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:176)
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.decode(CRS.java:517)
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.decode(CRS.java:433)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.read(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:258)
    ... 108 more
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like insufficient URL-decoding: `CRS.decode` most probably expects a string like `EPSG:3857` instead of `EPSG%3A3857`.

Whether GeoServer should URL-decode that value more or whether the data or a call contained a value that was [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_Encoding) once too many, I don't know: It could be

- that a non-encoded (plain) value was expected and an URL-encoded value was provided
  or
- that an URL-encoded value was expected and an URL-encoded value was provided, but not URL-decoded in GeoServer
  or
- that an URL-encoded value was expected and a doubly URL-encoded value was provided (and of course only URL-decoded once in GeoServer, thus an URL-decoded value remained instead of a plain one)