# Unexpected GeoServer behaviour when doing quickstart examples: Error occurred decoding the espg code EPSG:4326/kml?layers=topp:states

Tags: geoserver, ubuntu

I have installed GeoServer 2.16 on Ubuntu 18 using the directions [Here](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/installation/linux.html).

When I go to the [Layer Preview](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/webadmin/layerpreview.html#layerpreview) and try to access one of the built-in demo layers (`topp:states`) from the admin interface, I end up getting a file with the following:

```
      Error occurred decoding the espg code EPSG:4326/kml?layers=topp:states
No code &quot;EPSG:4326/KML?LAYERS=TOPP:STATES&quot; from authority &quot;European Petroleum Survey Group&quot; found for object of type &quot;IdentifiedObject&quot;.
</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

Whereas I expect to get a kml file based on the documentation [here](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/googleearth/quickstart.html)

It seems like the URL is not being read correctly and the EPSG code is read as`EPSG:4326/kml?layers=topp:states` instead of just `EPSG:4326`, which is a similar problem as is happening [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340086/error-occurred-decoding-the-epsg-code-epsg3a3857-in-geoserver) but I am using the example files, which should work out of the box.

This is what I get when I lauch GeoServer:

```
GEOSERVER DATA DIR is /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir
2020-01-10 12:00:02.929:INFO::main: Logging initialized @248ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2020-01-10 12:00:03.072:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Property 'jetty.port' is deprecated, use 'jetty.http.port' instead
2020-01-10 12:00:03.073:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Property 'http.timeout' is deprecated, use 'jetty.http.idleTimeout' instead
2020-01-10 12:00:03.078:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.18.v20190429; built: 2019-04-29T20:42:08.989Z; git: e1bc35120a6617ee3df052294e433f3a25ce7097; jvm 1.8.0_232-8u232-b09-0ubuntu1~18.04.1-b09
2020-01-10 12:00:03.093:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:///usr/share/geoserver/webapps/] at interval 1
2020-01-10 12:00:03.428:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /geoserver, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2020-01-10 12:00:03.786:INFO:oejs.session:main: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2020-01-10 12:00:03.786:INFO:oejs.session:main: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2020-01-10 12:00:03.787:INFO:oejs.session:main: node0 Scavenging every 600000ms
Jan 10, 2020 12:00:04 PM org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions checkContext
WARNING: Extension lookup 'XStreamPersisterInitializer', but ApplicationContext is unset.
Jan 10, 2020 12:00:04 PM org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions checkContext
WARNING: Extension lookup 'ExtensionFilter', but ApplicationContext is unset.
Jan 10, 2020 12:00:04 PM org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions checkContext
WARNING: Extension lookup 'ExtensionProvider', but ApplicationContext is unset.
Jan 10, 2020 12:00:04 PM org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions checkContext
WARNING: Extension lookup 'ExtensionFilter', but ApplicationContext is unset.
10 Jan 12:00:04 WARN [geoserver.logging] - log4jConfigFile 'DEFAULT_LOGGING.properties' couldn't be found in the data dir, so GeoServer will install the various logging config file into the data dir, and then try to find it again.
log4j:WARN File option not set for appender [geoserverlogfile].
log4j:WARN Are you using FileAppender instead of ConsoleAppender?
2020-01-10 12:00:04.404:INFO:oejshC.geoserver:main: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 10, 2020 12:00:06 PM org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions checkContext
WARNING: Extension lookup 'GeoServerSecurityProvider', but ApplicationContext is unset.
Jan 10, 2020 12:00:06 PM org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions checkContext
WARNING: Extension lookup 'ExtensionFilter', but ApplicationContext is unset.
Jan 10, 2020 12:00:06 PM org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions checkContext
WARNING: Extension lookup 'ExtensionProvider', but ApplicationContext is unset.
Jan 10, 2020 12:00:06 PM org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions checkContext
WARNING: Extension lookup 'ExtensionFilter', but ApplicationContext is unset.
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - GeoServer configuration lock is enabled
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loading catalog...
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'raster'
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'generic'
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'line'
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'burg'
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'poi'
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'point'
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'green'
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'population'
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'poly_landmarks'
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'simple_streams'
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'rain'
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'grass'
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'cite_lakes'
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'tiger_roads'
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'restricted'
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'pophatch'
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'capitals'
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'dem'
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'simple_roads'
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'polygon'
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded style 'giant_polygon'
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded default workspace cite
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'sde'
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'it.geosolutions'
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'tiger'
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'nurc'
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'topp'
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'cite'
10 Jan 12:00:06 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded workspace 'sf'
10 Jan 12:00:07 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'nyc', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'tiger_roads', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'tiger_roads'
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'giant_polygon', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'giant_polygon'
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'poi', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'poi'
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'poly_landmarks', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'poly_landmarks'
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'arcGridSample', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'Arc_Sample', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'Arc_Sample'
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'img_sample2', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'Pk50095', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'Pk50095'
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'mosaic', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'mosaic', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'mosaic'
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'worldImageSample', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'Img_Sample', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'Img_Sample'
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'taz_shapes', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'tasmania_roads', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'tasmania_roads'
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'tasmania_cities', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'tasmania_cities'
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'tasmania_water_bodies', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'tasmania_water_bodies'
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'tasmania_state_boundaries', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'tasmania_state_boundaries'
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'states_shapefile', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'states', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'states'
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded data store 'sf', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'roads', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'roads'
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'bugsites', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'bugsites'
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'restricted', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'restricted'
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'streams', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'streams'
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded feature type 'archsites', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'archsites'
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage store 'sfdem', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded coverage 'sfdem', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer 'sfdem'
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer group 'tasmania'
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer group 'tiger-ny'
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded layer group 'spearfish'
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Read catalog in 2.171 s
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'WMTSInfoImpl--22b054bc:16f90661ce7:-8000', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'wcs', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'wfs', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [org.geoserver] - Loaded service 'wms', enabled
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Will look for 'geowebcache.xml' in directory '/usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc'.
10 Jan 12:00:08 WARN [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Found no configuration file in config directory, will create one at 'gwc/geowebcache.xml' from template jar:file:/usr/share/geoserver/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gwc-core-1.16.1.jar!/geowebcache_empty.xml
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Found configuration file in gwc
10 Jan 12:00:08 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Found configuration file in gwc
10 Jan 12:00:08 WARN [config.XMLConfiguration] - ********************************************************************************
10 Jan 12:00:08 WARN [config.XMLConfiguration] - *** GWC configuration validation error: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'gwcConfiguration'.
10 Jan 12:00:08 WARN [config.XMLConfiguration] - *** Will try to use configuration anyway. Please check the order of declared elements against the schema.
10 Jan 12:00:08 WARN [config.XMLConfiguration] - ********************************************************************************
10 Jan 12:00:09 INFO [config.XMLConfiguration] - Initializing GridSets from gwc
10 Jan 12:00:09 INFO [config.XMLConfiguration] - Initializing layers from gwc
10 Jan 12:00:09 INFO [gwc.layer] - Initializing GWC configuration based on GeoServer's Catalog
10 Jan 12:00:09 INFO [gwc.layer] - GeoServer TileLayer store base directory is: gwc-layers
10 Jan 12:00:09 INFO [gwc.layer] - Loading tile layers from gwc-layers
10 Jan 12:00:09 INFO [gwc.layer] - Loaded 0 tile layers in 1.204 ms
10 Jan 12:00:09 INFO [storage.BlobStoreAggregator] - BlobStoreConfiguration gwc contained no blob store infos.
10 Jan 12:00:09 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - ********************************************************************************************************************************
10 Jan 12:00:09 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - *** Found Java environment variable GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR set to /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir, using it as the default prefix. ***
10 Jan 12:00:09 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - ********************************************************************************************************************************
10 Jan 12:00:09 INFO [gwc.config] - Initializing GeoServer specific GWC configuration from gwc-gs.xml
10 Jan 12:00:09 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Will look for 'geowebcache-diskquota.xml' in directory '/usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc'.
10 Jan 12:00:09 INFO [config.GeoserverXMLResourceProvider] - Will look for 'geowebcache-diskquota-jdbc.xml' in directory '/usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc'.
10 Jan 12:00:09 INFO [diskquota.ConfigLoader] - DiskQuota configuration is not readable: gwc/geowebcache-diskquota.xml
10 Jan 12:00:09 INFO [diskquota.ConfigLoader] - DiskQuota configuration is not readable: gwc/geowebcache-diskquota.xml
10 Jan 12:00:09 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Setting up disk quota periodic enforcement task
10 Jan 12:00:09 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - 0 layers configured with their own quotas. 
10 Jan 12:00:09 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - 22 layers attached to global quota 500.0 MB
10 Jan 12:00:09 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Disk quota periodic enforcement task set up every 10 SECONDS
10 Jan 12:00:09 INFO [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - Invoked setServletPrefix(gwc)
10 Jan 12:00:09 INFO [georss.GeoRSSPoller] - Initializing GeoRSS poller in a background job...
10 Jan 12:00:09 INFO [georss.GeoRSSPoller] - No enabled GeoRSS feeds found, poller will not run.
10 Jan 12:00:10 INFO [wms.WMSService] - Will NOT recombine tiles for non-tiling clients.
10 Jan 12:00:10 INFO [wms.WMSService] - Will proxy requests to backend that are not getmap or getcapabilities.
10 Jan 12:00:11 WARN [gce.imagemosaic] - Unable to set ordering between tiff readers spi
10 Jan 12:00:15 INFO [geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache Initialized with 1000 Max Entries, 300 seconds idle time, 600 seconds time to live and 3 concurrency level
10 Jan 12:00:15 INFO [geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache Eviction Task created to run every 600 seconds
10 Jan 12:00:15 INFO [geoserver.security] - Start reloading user/groups for service named default
10 Jan 12:00:15 INFO [geoserver.security] - Reloading user/groups successful for service named default
2020-01-10 12:00:16.175:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@56235b8e{GeoServer,/geoserver,file:///usr/share/geoserver/webapps/geoserver/,AVAILABLE}{/geoserver}
2020-01-10 12:00:16.193:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@33903444{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2020-01-10 12:00:16.194:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @13512ms
```

and when I actually request the KML the log shows:

```
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Error occurred decoding the espg code EPSG:4326/kml?layers=topp:states
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.read(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:266)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.read(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:90)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.parseRequestKVP(Dispatcher.java:1545)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:692)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1700)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1667)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:804)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchAuthorityCodeException: No code "EPSG:4326/KML?LAYERS=TOPP:STATES" from authority "European Petroleum Survey Group" found for object of type "IdentifiedObject".
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.AbstractAuthorityFactory.noSuchAuthorityCode(AbstractAuthorityFactory.java:874)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.PropertyAuthorityFactory.getWKT(PropertyAuthorityFactory.java:289)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.PropertyAuthorityFactory.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(PropertyAuthorityFactory.java:358)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.BufferedAuthorityFactory.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(BufferedAuthorityFactory.java:731)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.AuthorityFactoryAdapter.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(AuthorityFactoryAdapter.java:779)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.FallbackAuthorityFactory.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(FallbackAuthorityFactory.java:624)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.AuthorityFactoryAdapter.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(AuthorityFactoryAdapter.java:779)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.ThreadedAuthorityFactory.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(ThreadedAuthorityFactory.java:635)
    at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.createCoordinateReferenceSystem(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:176)
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.decode(CRS.java:517)
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.decode(CRS.java:433)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.read(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:258)
    ... 101 more
```

Comment: I had this same problem and traced it back to the `2020-01-10 12:00:03.428:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /geoserver, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet` line in the startup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right. The layer preview interface creates an invalid WMS GetMap request

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/topp/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=topp%3Astates&bbox=-124.73142200000001%2C24.955967%2C-66.969849%2C49.371735&width=768&height=330&srs=EPSG%3A4326/kml?layers=topp:states

Edit it a bit after the srs part and it will work

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/topp/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=topp%3Astates&bbox=-124.73142200000001%2C24.955967%2C-66.969849%2C49.371735&width=768&height=330&srs=EPSG%3A4326&format=kml&layers=topp:states

The issue seems to be a regression in GeoServer 2.16 because there is no error in  version 2.14.2 that makes a request in a quite different way

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/topp/wms/kml?layers=topp:states

It seems that there has been a plan to improve the demo query but everything did not go totally right.

I think that you have enough detais for creating a ticket to the GeoServer Jira https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/projects/GEOS/summary.

Comment: Did you raise a bug ticket for this?

Comment: No, I left that honour to @alex_danielssen.

Comment: Ticket https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-9459 deals with this.