# Why can't I translate GeoServer layers to KML?

Tags: geoserver, kml

I have installed GeoServer 2.16.1 on two independent servers; but both are unable to translate layers to KML (Keyhole Mark-up Language). I receive the following content instead of the KML:

```
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1">
    <ServiceException code="InvalidSRS">
        Error occurred decoding the espg code EPSG:2908/kml?layers=nyc:nyc_buildings No code "EPSG:2908/KML?LAYERS=NYC:NYC_BUILDINGS" from authority "European Petroleum Survey Group" found for object of type "IdentifiedObject".
</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

Apparently, the server is trying to interpret "EPSG:2908/KML?LAYERS=NYC:NYC_BUILDINGS" as the EPSG code, instead of just "EPSG:2908".

The URL to generate the KML is:

> localhost:8080/geoserver/nyc/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=nyc%3Anyc_buildings&bbox=983797.5%2C207443.0%2C991899.0625%2C218850.828125&width=545&height=768&srs=EPSG%3A2908/kml?layers=nyc:nyc_buildings

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add more information to your question, we need to know what URL parameters you are using

Comment: @IanTurton. Does this help?
localhost:8080/geoserver/nyc/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=nyc%3Anyc_buildings&bbox=983797.5%2C207443.0%2C991899.0625%2C218850.828125&width=545&height=768&srs=EPSG%3A2908/kml?layers=nyc:nyc_buildings

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add more information to your question - once it is edited it becomes eligible for reopening

Comment: The KML output in the layer preview of GeoServer 2.16 is broken. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347107/unexpected-geoserver-behaviour-when-doing-quickstart-examples-error-occurred-de/347135#347135. However, you are getting the error from your own client, don't you?

Comment: @user30184. I don't know what side of the program is generating the problem. Since both client and server are the same application, on the same server, it's difficult to tell.

Comment: I guess then that you are using the layer preview that comes with GeoServer and that has a bug that came after version 2.14. As a workaround you could install version 2.14.

Comment: @user30184. Yes. That seems to be the reason. Post it as a formal answer, if you want.

Comment: I think that I answered already in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347107/unexpected-geoserver-behaviour-when-doing-quickstart-examples-error-occurred-de/347135#347135. The question was a bit different, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question already answered here: [Unexpected GeoServer behaviour when doing quickstart examples: Error occurred decoding the espg code EPSG:4326/kml?layers=topp:states](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347107/unexpected-geoserver-behaviour-when-doing-quickstart-examples-error-occurred-de/347135#347135)

There is a bug in this particular version of GeoServer (2.16.1).

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are not making a valid WMS request - try something like

```
localhost:8080/geoserver/nyc/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=nyc%3Anyc_buildings&bbox=983797.5%2C207443.0%2C991899.0625%2C218850.828125&width=545&height=768&srs=EPSG%3A2908&format=application/vnd.google-earth.kml+XML
```

or if you want to use the [KML reflector](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/googleearth/features/kmlreflector.html) which doesn't support changing the SRS.

```
localhost:8080/geoserver/nyc/wms/kml?layers=nyc:nyc_buildings
```

Comment: I will try this request next Thursday. I don't have access to the server right now. But, anyway, the request is produced by GeoServer itself; so it must a bug of this particular version.

Comment: I have tried the requests on another GeoServer (same version). But they don't seem to be working. The server returns 'HTTP Status 404 – Not Found'. :(

Comment: Well. It did work on the server. The requests produced some XML, which looks like the desired result. Now I'm trying to sort out how these working URLs are generated, so I don't have to ask for help each time I want to generate one.

Comment: I up-vote your answer, because it helped bring light into the problem. But I believe it was user30184 who truly answered the question. Since I asked "*why* I can't..."; not "how could I manually fix...".